# How can I change the objects speed movement at run time but only once each time?

Tags: unity, c#

The is a bit long but I separated the relevant parts at the bottom of the question.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Objects To Move")]
    public Transform objectToMovePrefab;
    public int numberOfObjectsToMove = 1;

    [Header("Speed")]
    public float speed;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    public float minRandomSpeed = 1;
    public float maxRandomSpeed = 100;
    private bool changeSpeedOnce = false;

    [Header("Rotation")]
    public Quaternion rotationTothinkWhatToDoHere;

    [Header("Waypoints")]
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> waypoints;
    public bool moveOnWaypoints = false;

    [Header("Delay")]
    public bool useDelay = false;
    public float delay = 3;
    public bool randomDelay = false;
    public float minRandomDelay = 0.3f;
    public float maxRandomDelay = 5;

    [Header("LineRenderer")]
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public bool moveOnLineRenderer = false;
    public List<Vector3> lineRendererPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    [Header("Cinemachine Cameras")]
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCamera;

    private List<WaypointsFollower> waypointsFollowers = new List<WaypointsFollower>();

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToMove; i++)
        {
            var parent = GameObject.Find("Moving Object Parent");
            var objectToMove = Instantiate(objectToMovePrefab, parent.transform);
            objectToMove.name = "Platfrom";

            waypointsFollowers.Add(objectToMove.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>());
        }

        virtualCamera.Follow = waypointsFollowers[0].gameObject.transform;
        virtualCamera.LookAt = waypointsFollowers[0].gameObject.transform;

        WaypointsMovementStates();

        SpeedUpdater();

        if (useDelay)
            StartCoroutine(SendObjectstomoveWithDelay());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (moveOnLineRenderer)
        {
            lineRendererPositions.Clear();

            if (moveOnWaypoints)
            {
                foreach (Transform wp in waypoints)
                {
                    lineRendererPositions.Add(wp.position);
                }
            }

            lineRendererPositions.AddRange(GetLinePointsInWorldSpace());
        }

        SpeedUpdater();
    }

    IEnumerator SendObjectstomoveWithDelay()
    {
        {
            foreach (WaypointsFollower follower in waypointsFollowers)
            {
                if (randomDelay)
                {
                    delay = Random.Range(minRandomDelay, maxRandomDelay);
                }

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

                follower.go = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SpeedUpdater()
    {
        if (changeSpeedOnce == false)
        {
            foreach (WaypointsFollower follower in waypointsFollowers)
            {
                if (randomSpeed)
                {
                    follower.speed = Random.Range(minRandomSpeed, maxRandomSpeed);
                }
                else
                {
                    follower.speed = speed;
                }
            }

            changeSpeedOnce = true;
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        var positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    private void WaypointsMovementStates()
    {
        // If moving on both linerenderer positions and waypoints objects
        if (moveOnLineRenderer && moveOnWaypoints && waypoints.Count > 0)
        {
            if (useDelay == false)
            {
                foreach (WaypointsFollower wpf in waypointsFollowers)
                {
                    wpf.go = true;
                }
            }
        }


        // If moving on linerenderer positions only without moving on waypoints objects
        if (moveOnLineRenderer && moveOnWaypoints == false)
        {
            if (waypoints.Count > 0)
                waypoints.Clear();

            if (useDelay == false)
            {
                foreach (WaypointsFollower wpf in waypointsFollowers)
                {
                    wpf.go = true;
                }
            }
        }


        // If only to move on waypoints objects without moving on linerenderer positions
        if (moveOnWaypoints && waypoints.Count > 0 && moveOnLineRenderer == false)
        {
            lineRendererPositions.Clear();

            foreach (Transform wp in waypoints)
            {
                lineRendererPositions.Add(wp.position);
            }

            if (useDelay == false)
            {
                foreach (WaypointsFollower wpf in waypointsFollowers)
                {
                    wpf.go = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method SpeedUpdater I call it in the Update :

```
private void SpeedUpdater()
    {
        if (changeSpeedOnce == false)
        {
            foreach (WaypointsFollower follower in waypointsFollowers)
            {
                if (randomSpeed)
                {
                    follower.speed = Random.Range(minRandomSpeed, maxRandomSpeed);
                }
                else
                {
                    follower.speed = speed;
                }
            }

            changeSpeedOnce = true;
        }
    }
```

and I'm using helper flag bool name changeSpeedOnce. If the randomSpeed is true I want it to give each moving object a random speed once the problem is if I want to change the flag randomSpeed at run time for example if at run time I change the randomSpeed to false then make all the objects move in the same speed and if I set it to true again in the run time give each one again a random speed value but only once.

If I don't use the helper flag changeSpeedOnce and set the randomSpeed to true it will stutter because it will give each moving object a new random speed value every frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case only use *Update()* for 2 things:

1. To check if way point already is reached;
2. If not yet, move gameobject small incremental distance;

Other parameters of gameobject, - ,such as speed, should be stored in easy accessible manner and its value set *only when you require*, NOT every frame in *Update()*.
This is how I move units in my RTS game.

This would be simplified example of code:

```
public bool isMoving;
public Vector3 nextPoint;
public float speed;

private Vector3 dir = new Vector3();
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isMoving)
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, nextPoint) < 0.5f)   //are we there yet?
        {
            isMoving = false;

        }
        else
        {
            dir = (nextPoint - transform.position).normalized;  // direction of movement (also could be moved outside Update() function in most cases)
            transform.Translate(dir * speed);  // move a little bit!
        }

    }

}
```

Note: *dir* here is directional vector pointing from current position of gameobject to position of *nextPoint*.

*speed* here defines how far object is moved every frame. Basically speed of object. Can be set from everywhere.